# Init Script Issue (Embedded Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, embedded-linux

I need to write some init scripts about serial port in my project . I researched related post in forums but I get some problem about it.

I m using embedded linux , so I am using chkconfig for adding scripts to system.

### BEGIN INIT INFO

# Provides: myservice

# Required-Start:     $local_fs $remove_fs

# Required-Stop:      $local_fs $remove_fs

# Default-Start:      2 3 4 5

# Default-Stop:       0 1

# Short-Description:  myservice

# Description:        giving chmod o+rw /dev/ttymxc0 permission

### END INIT INFO

. /etc/init.d/functions

case "$1" in

start)

```
    chmod o+rw /dev/ttymxc0 
    ;;
```

stop)

```
   echo -n "My service is stopped"
   ;;
```

*)
       exit 1
esac

exit 0

I m saving and  `chkconfig --add init.sh chkconfig init.sh on` then I m giving chmod +x init.sh  permission to my script too.

After I restart my development board I check the permission of my serialport like;
`ls -la /dev/ttymxc0`

and There is nothing changed .
My init script doesnt work . Am I missing something? Or Am I doing wrong ?
Can you help me about that.

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Add output of `runlevel` and `chkconfig --list init.sh` to your question.

Comment: output is 0:off 1:on 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off

Comment: Your `case` syntax is broken and I suggest to add a shebang. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean case syntax is broken ?

Comment: This seems like it should be a udev rule, not an init script. Have a look at http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#ownership. A rule like `KERNEL=="ttymxc[0-9]", MODE="0660"` might be all you need.